# How to conditionally display some things in the message text created by the Message module?

Tags: 7, message-subscribe

I am using the [Message](http://https:/www./drupal.org/project/message) module to record some activity.

I have a Rule generating a Message. The Message Type has a couple of fields, and I am setting them in the rule. That part all works great. I can verify the contents of each of those message fields.

Now what I'm trying to do is to conditionally display some things in the message text. I have a couple of Message Text rows and they all display what I expect them to. But for one of these, I want only want to display something if one of the tokens matches a condition.

I have selected the PHP Code filter type on that particular Message Text box, but I just don't know to actually evaluate the field values of the current message. I've tried t() and token_replace() and I just am not getting it.

So here is a simple question for this problem I'm having. Say I have a text field on this message type called field_foo. And I want the message text to display the length of that field. I basically want something to the effect of `<?php strlen(this-message:field_foo) ?>`.

How do I reference my message instance's field?

Comment: To clarify: are you asking about how to conditionally display a field (or information that depends on the contents of a field) attached to a custom content type "message"? And when you say "token" do you mean an actual Drupal token: https://drupal.org/project/token?

Comment: I go to Structure > Message Types. I click Edit on my message type. In one of the "Message Text" boxes, I want to put the equivalent of <?php strlen('[message:field_foo']) ?>, but that works and actually outputs the length of that message type field set for that particular message.

Comment: OK, so you're using the Message module, right? And you're trying to figure out how to evaluate the contents of a text field attached to a message and display something conditionally based on what you find in the field?

Comment: Quite so! I'll get the conditional logic part if I can actually figure out how to reference my field vlaues. That's the part I can't seem to crack.

Comment: The message module provides access to tokens in two forms: field_foo and field-foo (note the hyphen). I believe you should use the hyphenated form when you want to work with the field value. Did you try that?

Comment: I have tried both _ and -. <?php strlen('[message:field-foo]') ?> just uses the string '[message:field-foo]'. I'm trying to make it use the value of the field field_foo.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do this what I thought was the "right" way - that being inside the message type itself.

Instead, I added a preprocess field from DisplaySuite and put that into my display.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_message(&$variables) {
    $message = $variables['elements']['#entity'];
    if (isset($message) && $message->type == 'my_custom_message' && isset($message->field_foo) && array_key_exists(LANGUAGE_NONE, $message->field_attachment_themed)) {
        $html = $message->field_fooLANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
        $variables['parsed_output'] = $html;
    }
}
```

Then I just named my preprocess field parsed_output, and it now displays exactly how I want, and I can add whatever custom code I want to my preprocess_message().